# Finding the dimension of eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> For example, suppose you're given a $ 6 \times 6 $
> matrix and you calculate that its characteristic polynomial is $(t-3)^4(t-i)^2$, that its minimal polynomial is $(t-3)^2 (t-i)^2$, that the $3$-eigenspace is $3$-dimensional, and that the $i$-eigenspace is $1$-dimensional.

I have a problem in understanding how author find the dimension of eigenspace of $3$ and $1$. How can I find them?

Comment: Who is the author?  What is the source of the quote?

Comment: Can you give some more context to the quotation? As it is currently quoted, it simply asks the reader to suppose they have calculated 4 things, the characteristic polynomial, the minimal polynomial, the dimension of the 3-eigenspace and the dimension of the i-eigenspace. No claim is made within the quotation that any of these 4 were deduced from any of the others. In other words, as quoted, the author's hypothesis is that the min. poly., char. poly. and dimensions of eigenspaces of a 6x6 matrix have all been computed, without claiming anything about how these things were computed.

Answer (score 0):

Let us take for example the eigenvalue $\;\lambda=3\;$: that the exponent of its linear factor in the minimal polynomial is two means that two is the largest block in the Jordan Block (=JB) corresponding to $\;3\;$, which means that the JB, which clearly has size $\;4\times4\;$ , has exactly three blocks: one of size two, two of size one. Something like the following, with the different colors marking the different block in $\;JB_3\;$ :

$$JB_{\lambda=3}=\begin{pmatrix}
\color{red}3&\color{red}1&0&0\\
\color{red}0&\color{red}3&0&0\\
0&0&\color{green}3&0\\
0&0&0&\color{blue}3\end{pmatrix}$$

Since the number of blocks in $\;JB_\lambda\;$ gives us $\;\dim V_\lambda\;$ ,we're done.

Comment: Isn't two Jordan blocks of size 2 a possibility?

Comment: Cause the minimal polynomial exponent is the largest JB, but I could be wrong, I am still studying it in uni.

Comment: @RabMakh You're completely correct, but in this case *we're given* that $\;\dim V_3=3\;$ , so there can't be only two blocks but three.

Comment: Hmm...wait, re-reading your question, the eigenspace's dimension is **not** given, right? If so, then there exist two possibilities, indeed: what I wrote and two $\';2\times2\;$ blocks, I believe.

Comment: @DonAntonio "3-eigenspace is 3-dimensional", it is given ...

Comment: @PeterMelech No, it's not. that that you quote is given as an example...

Comment: @DonAntonio Ok, then I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

That implies its Jordan normal form is:

$\begin{pmatrix}3&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&3&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&3&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&3&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&i&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&i\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: why we don't have two 2*2 blocks for eigenvalue 3?

Comment: Because the dimension of the eigenspace is 3, there must be three Jordan blocks, each one containing one entry corresponding to an eigenvector, because of the exponent 2 in the minimal polynomial the first block is 2*2, the remaining blocks must be 1*1

Answer (score 0):

The Jordan form of your matrix must be of the type$$\begin{pmatrix}3&*&0&0&0&0\\0&3&*&0&0&0\\0&0&3&*&0&0\\0&0&0&3&0&0\\0&0&0&0&i&*\\0&0&0&0&0&i\end{pmatrix},$$where each $*$ is either $0$ or $1$. But if, for instance, the $*$ from the fifth row is equal to $0$, then the exponent of $t-i$ in the minimal polynomial of the matrix must be $1$. Since it is $2$, that $*$ must be equal to $1$. Now, see what the other three $*$ must be so that the exponent of $t-3$ in the minimal polynomial of the matrix is $2$.